# How can I understand the kernel of tf.keras.layers.Dense for rank >2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How can I understand the kernel of `tf.keras.layers.Dense` for rank >2?

The official API doc states that:

> Note: If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then Dense
> computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the
> last axis of the inputs and axis 0 of the kernel (using tf.tensordot).
> For example, if input has dimensions (batch_size, d0, d1), then we
> create a kernel with shape (d1, units), and the kernel operates along
> axis 2 of the input, on every sub-tensor of shape (1, 1, d1) (there
> are batch_size * d0 such sub-tensors). The output in this case will
> have shape (batch_size, d0, units).

My understanding is that for a rank larger than 2 (for example rank 3) only **one** kernel is created and thus the same kernel is applied on all slices of the second dimension, like above.
That would consequently mean that the outputs for different indices of the second dimension are **not independent** of each other (especially during training).

Is my understanding correct? And if yes, is there a simple way to use a stack of kernels instead or do I have to implement the tensor multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

To achieve what you want, you need to define a custom keras layer. Let's suppose the input to the layer is of shape (batch_size, d0, i0). Most part of the layer will be similar to the original `Dense` layer (link: [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/22ffec3a9c44133cba2182d60678d49bb372f020/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L1077)), except that

1. In the `build` function, the shape of `self.kernel` is (d0, i0, units) instead. You can get the value of `d0` as well as `i0` from `input_shape`.
2. In the `call` function, to do the specified tensor multiplication between `inputs` and `self.kernel`, use `tf.einsum` with this equation: `tf.einsum('abc,bcg->abg', inputs, self.kernel)`